# Replacing multiple variables in a file

Tags: javascript

I am using a simple javascript to readfile, and replace few variables in my input file and write an updated to an output file

my input file has

IP `{IPADDR}` Subnet `{SMASK).`

I have been using this and doesnt work for second variable.

`var rFile = inputFile.replace(/IPADDR/g, '182.10.10.1' /SMASK/g, '255.0.0.0');`

It only updates `IPADDR`, but not `SMASK`.

Any pointers?

Comment: Replace `var rFile =inputFile.replace(/IPADDR/g, '182.10.10.1' /SMASK/g, '255.0.0.0');` to `var rFile = inputFile.replace(/IPADDR/g, '182.10.10.1' ).replace(/SMASK/g, '255.0.0.0');`

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use multiple values inside of `.replace()`. You can either chain them like this:

```
let inputFile = 'IP {IPADDR} Subnet {SMASK).';

var rFile = inputFile
  .replace(/IPADDR/g, '182.10.10.1')
  .replace(/SMASK/g, '255.0.0.0');

return rFile; // 'IP {182.10.10.1} Subnet {255.0.0.0).'
```

Or you can create a function to help you in the future:

```
// In the same file or an another.js
const replace = (text, data) => {
  let replacedText = text;

  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), data[key])
  });

  return replacedText;
}

// And your code
let inputFile = 'IP {IPADDR} Subnet {SMASK).';

const data = {
  'IPADDR': '182.10.10.1',
  'SMASK': '255.0.0.0',
}

const rFile = replace(inputFile, data); // 'IP {182.10.10.1} Subnet {255.0.0.0).'
```